# Android NavController get backstack

Tags: android-architecture-navigation

We use `NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener` and the provided parameter `NavDestination` to hide/show the bottom navigation bar (which is anchored in the root activity) depending on the current destination. But our logic requires also to know which was the previous destination for the current destination in order to hide/show the bottom navigation bar.

`NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener` also provides a `NavController` parameter, and `NavController` has an internal property called `mBackStack` which seems to be precisely what we need. So, is there a way to access the NavController backstack without using reflection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to infer the `NavDestination`(s) which are currently in the backstack by accessing all the destinations in the graph and then calling `navController.getBackStackEntry` in each one of them.

```
val destinationsInBackStack = navController.graph.mapNotNull { dest ->
    try {
        navController.getBackStackEntry(dest.id)
        dest
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to know which order they are in?

Comment: I guess the iteration order is the order in which they has been added to the task

Comment: Just be aware that `getBackStackEntry` returns the topmost entry, if you have multiple entries in the backstack of the same fragment, it will not be returned